# getting error while using table(Data stream) in flink

Tags: scala, csv, sbt, apache-flink, flink-cep

I'm using flink 1.9.0 and I'm unable to import or get table files

I've tried importing different SBTs related to it

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val tEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)

    val tempSource = CsvTableSource.builder()
      .path("/home/amulya/Desktop/csvForBroadcast/CSV.csv")
      .fieldDelimiter(",")
      .field("locationID", Types.STRING())
      .field("temp", Types.DOUBLE())
      .build()

    tEnv.registerTableSource("Temperatures", tempSource)

    val askTable = tEnv
      .scan("Temperatures")
      .where(" 'Temperature >= 50")
      .select("'locationID, 'temp")

    val stream = tEnv.toAppendStream[Events](askTable)
      .print()
    env.execute()


  }
  case class Events(locationID: String, temp: Long)
}
```

I've a simple data of CSV format:-

```
locationID,temp
"1",25
"2",25
"3",35
"4",45
"5",55
```

This is the error :-

```
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'ScalaCaseClassSerializer.class'.
Could not access type SelfResolvingTypeSerializer in object org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerConfigSnapshot,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'ScalaCaseClassSerializer.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerConfigSnapshot.
```

I'm trying to perform CEP on this basic data so as to get started with apache flink, any kind of help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try flink-table-api-java-bridge.

Currently scala bridge module only provides basic transformation between table and dataset/datastream.

Comment: Thanks alot , I'll try and let you know if it works for me

Comment: It worked but there's further problem coming while using filter, `cannot resolve overloaded method filter`

Comment: It'd be better if you add your codes in description. I don't see any filter in picture.

Comment: Done, Kindly check now

Comment: Remove the " at the end of the expression in filter.